# How to check given number is decimal or not in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, decimal

I want to check weather given number is decimal or not if it's decimal it should return decimal or else it should return integer.

I tried many solutions from the internet it's failing some conditions, please help me to acheive this thing.

It should return **decimal** if it's this format also **10.00, 10.0 ,99.000** .

```
$value=$request->amount;//99.99,99.00...
if(gettype($value)){
 if(decimal){
 //My logic goes here.
}
if(integer){
//My logic
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:

```
$value=$request->amount;

if(fmod($value, 1) !== 0.00){
    //It is decimal, so the decimal logic goes here.
} else {
    // It is an Intereger, so the ineteger logic goes here.
}
```

fmod(x,y) is a PHP function that returns the remainder of x/y.

You simply set y=1, the number (here is x) is an Integer only if the remainder of x/1 equals 0.00.

For example:

the output of fmod(10.05,1) is 0.05 so it is decimal
the output of fmod(5,1) is 0 so it is an integer

If you want to learn more about fmod function, pay a visit to [fmod function description](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_math_fmod.asp)

Note: you can even pass a string to fmod function and it will automatically change to a number.

For example:

the output of fmod('34.04',1) is 0.04 and it is decimal

Comment: It's failing if I search value with 20.00, like this values also it's should be a decimal value

Comment: 20.00 is an Integer, not a decimal.

Comment: What is the type of $request->amount variable? if it's an integer there is no way to put 20.00 in it, it will automatically turn to 20. but if it's a string there is a way to find dot(.) in the string. check out strpos() function